# Browser related

Tags: html, browser

I am running into an issue where URL with querystring parameters separated by & is not getting resolved correctly.
Can anyone please guide on this?
For instance - 
consider url 
https://www.google.com/?gws_rd#q=Pune&tbm=news resolves to 'news' tab 
but https://www.google.com/? gws_rd#q=Pune&tbm=news lands on 'All' tab of google.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `#` character indicates the end of the query string and the start of the fragment identifier.

You have to escape it (as `%23`) if you want it to appear as data.